# QR Code Detection from Pyzbar with Camera Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, qr-code

I am having trouble detecting QR code using Pyzbar. Under perfection condition, I am able to detect the QR code using the original png image. However, when I do video capture from a camera, and then save that frame as in image, pyzbar fails to detect the QR code.

For example, this works

[image]

```
[Decoded(data=b'GOAL', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=16, top=16, width=168, height=168))]
```

But the following does not even after I manually cropped the surroundings to only show the QR code.

[image]

```
[]
```

For both of the images, I am using

```
decode(image, scan_locations=True)
```

I am wondering what do I need to do in order for pyzbar to decode my QR code image?

Comment: Try normalizing, or (probably even better) binarizing the image to improve contrast. There's also a fair amount of distortion, you might want to consider fixing that too.

Answer (score 8):

Used `OpenCV` to threshold the image to black-in-white then `pyzbar` is able to decode the QR code.

Firstly, threshold the image with the code below.

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import argparse
import numpy as np
import cv2

image =cv2.imread("QRCode.png")

# thresholds image to white in back then invert it to black in white
#   try to just the BGR values of inRange to get the best result
mask = cv2.inRange(image,(0,0,0),(200,200,200))
thresholded = cv2.cvtColor(mask,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
inverted = 255-thresholded # black-in-white
```

The following is the processed images.

[image]

With,

```
barcodes = pyzbar.decode(inverted)
print (barcodes)
```

The print out showed the decoded type is `QRCODE` and the data is `GOAL`.

```
[Decoded(data='GOAL', type='QRCODE', rect=Rect(left=5, top=13, width=228, height=212), 
polygon=[Point(x=5, y=222), Point(x=233, y=225), Point(x=220, y=19), Point(x=13, y=13)])]
```

Hope this help.

Comment: What is your variable `mask` ?

Comment: @cactuschibre `thresholded`

Comment: @Tinti Have separated the thresholded and inverted into two lines for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: What is the meaning of putting max hue = 200 (in `inRange`) when opencv supports Hue in 0-179 range ? This looks like an accidental, and won't work always.

Comment: @AvinashThakur it's to mask the `image` with `BGR(200,200,200)` before thresholding.

Comment: @thewaywewere My mistake. I thought it's HSV. Anyways, masking all colors from (0,0,0) to (200,200,200) as one won't work always especially in less bright images.

Answer (score 2):

I found the existing answers didn't work for some images and ended up using this approach.

```py
''' detect and decode QR from image '''
def scan_qr(image, old_method=False):
    if image.ndim == 3:
        image_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else: # ndim == 2
        image_gray = image
    min_dim = min(image.shape[:2])
    block_size = int(min_dim/3)
    block_size += 0 if block_size%2 == 1 else 1 # blockSize should be odd
    image_bw = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image_gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, block_size, 2)
    return decode(image_bw, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.QRCODE])
```

I am using [adaptiveThreshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html#:%7E:text=image-,Adaptive%20Thresholding,-In%20the%20previous) as it is better in converting an image of varying brightness to a black & white image.

Your qr looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the problem you are facing is due to the fact that you flipped the image before processing

flipping the image after processing with pyzbar will make it align as you would want it to be